# What format are DMARC dates?

Tags: dmarc, date, timestamp, formatting

I have a DMARC report that includes:

```
<date_range>
  <begin>1500249600</begin>
  <end>1500335999</end>
</date_range>
```

How do I convert the dates to something human?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a converter from DMARC, here it is https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-xml/

And AFAIR there's also converted dates. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's just what I need

Answer (score 2):

Links below are outdated, currently for similar purpose one can use **https://www.unixtimestamp.com/**

> http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1500249600 gives:
> timestamp 1500249600 means:
> In your local time zone: Monday 17th July 2017 10:00:00 AM
> UTC: Monday 17th July 2017 12:00:00 AM

> http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1500335999 gives:
> timestamp 1500335999 means:
> In your local time zone: Tuesday 18th July 2017 09:59:59 AM
> UTC: Monday 17th July 2017 11:59:59 PM

Comment: These links are obsolete. See @Zonder's response which has working links.

Answer (score 2):

I just got same question today and came to this post from Google search :)

However, it seems that site link, mentioned in previous answer, is no longer exist.

Here are working links to a few of such time converters:

https://timestamp.online

https://www.unixtimestamp.com

https://www.epochconverter.com

Answer (score 2):

The `date` function in `bash` is quick and easy for casual conversion, such as when reading a DMARC report. On OSX:

```sh
$ date -jr 1606953599
Wed  2 Dec 2020 23:59:59 GMT
```

The `-j` flag prevents `date` from setting the date on your system. `-r` tells it there's a UNIX Time in seconds following, which is the DMARC report format for `date_range` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try on Linux command line:

```
date --date='@1500249600'
Sun 16 Jul 2017 05:00:00 PM PDT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a system with MySQL such as MacOS, etc, open up a CLI and type

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1500249600);
```

You'll get:
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1661212800) |
+---------------------------+
| 2022-08-22 17:00:00       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a system with MySQL such as MacOS, etc, open up a CLI and type

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1500249600);
```

You'll get:

> ```
> +---------------------------+
> | from_unixtime(1500249600) |
> +---------------------------+
> | 2017-07-16 17:00:00       |
> +---------------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.02 sec)
> ```